# The following assertion was thrown building EmployeesAndCompaniesTab(dirty): setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-getx

I working on Flutter mobile App and I'am using GetX as State manager.

I have this exception :

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building EmployeesAndCompaniesTab(dirty):
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

This Obx widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was: Obx
  has builder
  dirty
  state: _ObxState#14ad0
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was: EmployeesAndCompaniesTab
  dirty
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  EmployeesAndCompaniesTab EmployeesAndCompaniesTab:file:///search_screen.dart:98:19
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Element.markNeedsBuild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4476:11)
#1      Element.markNeedsBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4491:6)
#2      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1129:15)
#3      _ObxState._updateTree (package:get/get_state_manager/src/rx_flutter/rx_obx_widget.dart:41:7)
#4      GetStream._notifyData (package:get/get_rx/src/rx_stream/get_stream.dart:47:21)
#5      GetStream.add (package:get/get_rx/src/rx_stream/get_stream.dart:97:5)
#6      NotifyManager.addListener.<anonymous closure> (package:get/get_rx/src/rx_types/rx_core/rx_impl.dart:158:40)
#7      GetStream._notifyData (package:get/get_rx/src/rx_stream/get_stream.dart:47:21)
#8      GetStream.add (package:get/get_rx/src/rx_stream/get_stream.dart:97:5)
#9      RxObjectMixin.refresh (package:get/get_rx/src/rx_types/rx_core/rx_impl.dart:29:13)
#10     RxList.length= (package:get/get_rx/src/rx_types/rx_iterables/rx_list.dart:100:5)
#11     ListMixin.clear (dart:collection/list.dart:342:10)
#12     EmployeesAndCompaniesController.onSearch (package:/employees_and_companies_controller.dart:140:49)
#13     EmployeesAndCompaniesTab.build (package:/employees_and_companies_tab.dart:31:16)
#14     _GetCache.build (package:get/get_state_manager/src/simple/get_view.dart:103:20)
#15     GetWidgetCacheElement.build (package:get/get_state_manager/src/simple/get_widget_cache.dart:29:27)
#16     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4806:15)
#17     GetWidgetCacheElement.performRebuild (package:get/get_state_manager/src/simple/get_widget_cache.dart:35:11)
#18     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#19     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2659:19)
#20     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:891:21)
#21     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:370:5)
#22     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1146:15)
#23     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1083:9)
#24     SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:864:7)
(elided 4 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, and dart:async-patch)
```

There is my code of Parent Widget who contain Tabs:

```
class SearchScreen extends GetWidget<SearchController> {

  bool isParentReady = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String workSiteName = "";
        SearchScreenArgument passingValue =
        ModalRoute
        .of(context)!
        .settings
        .arguments as SearchScreenArgument;
    if (passingValue.tabIndex == 1) {
      controller.tabController.animateTo(
          (controller.tabController.index + passingValue.tabIndex!) % 2);
    }
    if (passingValue.worksiteName != null) {
      workSiteName = passingValue.worksiteName!;
    }

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title:  Text(workSiteName.toString(),
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              style: AppStyle
                  .textstylecircularstdbold241
                  .copyWith(
                  fontSize: getFontSize(24))),
          backgroundColor: ColorConstant.indigo600,
        ),
        backgroundColor: ColorConstant.whiteA700,
        body: Column(children: [
          Expanded(
              child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: getHorizontalSize(10.00),
                      top: getVerticalSize(21.00),
                      right: getHorizontalSize(10.00)),
                  child: TabBar(
                    controller: controller.tabController,
                    labelColor: ColorConstant.indigo600,
                    unselectedLabelColor: ColorConstant.gray700,
                    labelPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 2),
                    // TODO decrease height of indicator
                    indicator: RectangularIndicator(
                      color: ColorConstant.indigo60033,
                      bottomRightRadius: 2,
                      bottomLeftRadius: 2,
                      topLeftRadius: 2,
                      topRightRadius: 2,
                    ),
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(text: "search".tr),
                      Tab(text: "control".tr),
                    ],
                  )),
      Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child:
                TabBarView(controller: controller.tabController, children: [
                  EmployeesAndCompaniesTab(),
                  ChecklistScreen(),
                ]),
              )
            ],
          ))
        ]));
  }

}
```

Here is code of the Tab  EmployeesAndCompaniesTab(),

```
  class EmployeesAndCompaniesTab
  extends GetWidget<EmployeesAndCompaniesController> {
  var companies = <Company>[];
  String query = '';
  EmployeesAndCompaniesTab({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final EmployeesAndCompaniesController controller =
      Get.put(EmployeesAndCompaniesController());
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    controller.onSearch();
    final styleActive = TextStyle(color: Colors.black);
    final styleHint = TextStyle(color: Colors.black54);
    final style = controller.searchController.value.text.isEmpty
        ? styleHint
        : styleActive;

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: getHorizontalSize(40.00),
                      top: getHorizontalSize(10.00),
                      bottom: getHorizontalSize(20.00)),
                  child: Center(
                    child: TabChip(
                        onCheck: () => controller.onSearch(),
                        forceDisableCompanyChip:
                            controller.forceDisableCompanyChip.value),
                  ))),


          // search array
          Container(
            height: 60,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 16, 16, 5),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
              color: Colors.white,
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.black26),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                  spreadRadius: 5,
                  blurRadius: 7,
                  offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                ),
              ],
            ),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
            child: TextField(
              controller: controller.searchController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                icon: Icon(Icons.search, color: style.color),
                suffixIcon: controller.searchController.value.text.isNotEmpty
                    ? GestureDetector(
                        child: Icon(Icons.close, color: style.color),
                        onTap: () {
                          controller.searchController.clear();
                          controller.onSearch();
                          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                        },
                      )
                    : null,
                hintText: "Rechercher",
                hintStyle: style,
                border: InputBorder.none,
              ),
              style: style,
              onChanged: controller.onSearch(),
            ),
          ),

          // filters
          Obx(() => controller.searchedCompanyName.value.isNotEmpty
              ? Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: getHorizontalSize(15.00),
                  ),
                  child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      child: InputChip(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        onDeleted: () {
                          controller.onSearch();
                          controller.searchedCompanyName.value =
                              ""; // TODO remplace "" by Constant.empty
                          controller.searchedCompanyId = -1;
                        },
                        avatar: const Icon(
                          Icons.filter,
                          size: 20,
                          color: Colors.black54,
                        ),
                        deleteIconColor: Colors.black54,
                        label: Text("Société : " +
                            controller.searchedCompanyName.value),
                      )))
              : Text('')),

          Obx(() => ListView.builder(
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount:
                  controller.companyModelObj.value.companyItemList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                CompanyItemModel model =
                    controller.companyModelObj.value.companyItemList[index];
                return CompanyItemWidget(
                  model,
                  onTapTxtAccder: () => onTapCompanyDetailBtn(context, model),
                );
              })),
          // TODO empty text, when nothing
          Obx(() => ListView.builder(
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount:
                  controller.employeeModelObj.value.employeeItemList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                EmployeeItemModel model =
                    controller.employeeModelObj.value.employeeItemList[index];
                if (controller.employeeModelObj.value.employeeItemList.length <
                        1 ||
                    controller.employeeModelObj.value.employeeItemList == null)
                  return Center(child: Text("Empty"));
                return EmployeeItemWidget(
                  model,
                  onTapTxtAccder: () => {onTapScanEmployeeBtn(context, model)},
                );
              }))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I'am struggling with this, Help please.

Answer (score 0):

What's the code here search_screen.dart:98:19?

Anyway (as the exception says) this type of error happends when the build method is called while is already building, probably there is a stream or the tabController that triggers the rebuild too early.

Comment: I think you'd like to talk about EmployeesAndCompaniesTab:98:19 instead of search_screen.dart:98:19, because there no line 98 in search_screen.dart.

Comment: But in EmployeesAndCompaniesTab:98:19 I have ListView.builder whose state is updated as you said by Get Obx: ` Obx(() => ListView.builder(
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
           
   `

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).